# MBI5026 led driver datasheet question

Tags: led-driver, shift-register, latch

I've bought many MBI5026GF driver ICs.
based on the datasheet, the IC set up with MCU and other components is very similar to 74HC595 (Serial to parallel procedure) but with 16 bits of data per IC.

but I don't understand how the LE pin works. (it's supposed to make the latching happen.)
the pin description is not clear to me. (when it gets low data is latched to output pins ? or when it's low?)

which way is correct to code my mCU ?

1. set LE low. send serial data. set LE high.
2. set LE high. send serial data. set LE low.

should OE be always low when all these happens ?

[Datasheet Link](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1284473/ETC1/MBI5024GF.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Latch Enable (LE) is high, the data in the shift register will immediately appear on the LEDs. So, you don't want it high while you are loading the shift register or the LEDs might flicker.

#1 is better than #2, but I would do it this way.

Start with LE low. Load the shift register, then set LE high momentarily. Keep it low until after you have loaded data again.

[image]

Comment: thanks. actually that same table in datasheet confused me. in LE description it says latching happens with LE being high, then says low. I understand now.